# a program has an access on a file to read the current water level and give a warning when the water level is more than 15 meter

Tags: java

I don't know how to read the last line from the file so it will also be saved in `waterlevel`.

I have to make in addition to the code a strukogram.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.ioException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
    
public class Dam{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileWriter fw;
        FileReader fr;
        int waterLevel;
        String text;
    
        do { 
            System.out.println("give the current water level");
    
            try {
                fw = new FileWriter("waterLevel.txt");
                text = sc.nextInt()+ "\n";
    
                fw.write(text,0,text.length());
                fw.flush();
                fw.close;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
    
        } while (waterLevel < 15);

        System.out.println("warning");        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to *read* from the file, why are you writing to it instead? Please [edit] your question to clarify what the program is supposed to do, including what the expected inputs and outputs are, and including a relevant part of the input file.

Comment: Not sure whether the edit introduced it, but the code given above does not even compile. Check `main(Strin[]args)`

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri what's changed in edits is [available](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70018394/revisions) for everyone to see. Anyway, looks like an unrelated typo, I'll fix it myself.

Comment: The code is evident to read from STDIN and write to a file named waterlevel.txt. So I guess that the problem is to read the last line from STDIN. This question has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660942/java-how-do-i-get-last-line-using-scanner